# Kendo grid maximum no of columns grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In the below screen shot display the three columns in the Kendo grid. I am enable the grouping option. All the three columns are grouping. But I need grouping only two columns. How can I do that (i.e., Maximum no.of grid columns-1).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is better that making a column non-groupable

```
columns.Bound(r => r.NAME).Groupable(false);
```

Comment: I don't know the particular column is non groupable. i.e, first time am group in s.no and city and second time is s.no and name and third is name and city. this time what I do. I need the code in jQuery itself. because am write the program in mvvm model (html code only) not in mvc.